# Rails 3.2.3 sqlite gem not install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I changed my MAC OSX version to Lion. After that, I try to create a new Rails 3.2.3 App. However there is a error like while running bundle install,

> Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions 
>   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> ```
>     /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb  checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create
> ```
>
> Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries
>   and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
>   need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
>     --with-sqlite3-dir  --without-sqlite3-dir   --with-sqlite3-include
>     --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include    --with-sqlite3-lib
>     --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib    --enable-local
>     --disable-local
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in
>   `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
>   (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.   from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in`
>   try_cpp'     from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in
>   `block in find_header'    from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in`
>   block in checking_for'   from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in
>   `block (2 levels) in postpone'    from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`
>   open'    from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in
>   `block in postpone'   from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`
>   open'    from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in
>   `postpone'    from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in`
>   checking_for'    from
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in
>   `find_header'     from extconf.rb:34:in`'
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
>   An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

When I try

> gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'

I see the same error.

What should I do to fix it?

thanks.

---

I updated the gems but in this time json error occurs

```
Installing json (1.6.6) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.6.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.6.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.6.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.6.6'` succeeds before bundling.
enders-MacBook-Pro:kodcu ender$ gem install json -v '1.6.6'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.6.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.6.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2):

Try reinstalling/upgrading your Xcode. And then try installing sqlite again

Comment: After a major OS upgrade like this, it's a great idea to completely wipe and re-install all your rubies and gems.

Comment: Yes. I am installing Xcode 4.3.2 now. But I dont know how it will be upgraded because I already have got Xcode 3.2...

Comment: I installed Xcode 4, but I still have Xcode3. should I remove it with all dicractories?